# Is there a certain tool for nice website designs?

Tags: templates

I see a lot of webpages with a similar, simple design and certain features such as shadowed fonts. I wonder if they all used some tool or website builder, perhaps with predefined,but modifiable designs?
Here are some examples what I mean:

http://roaringapps.com

http://urbanairship.com

http://omz-software.com

So were those sites designed by hand (in which case the question is off-topic I guess) or is there some well-known webdesign / programming tool which helped here?

Reason I ask: I would like to redesign my own page in the same style as above, I can do everything except the design. So if I could get my hands on a tool which helps me designing a template, I could easily translate that to html/css and some logic in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sites you list are using something called [Content Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) which is a set of files installed on the server and executed by the server when someone requests a page.

The sites you list all use different systems, and the similarity between them is (probably) purely coincidental.

Comment: Hello Joachim, thanks for your help! I now what a CMS though :) I was going specifically at the design and hoped someone would say "Ah yes, tool X has those templates built-in". I figured these sites are developers in the first place and perhaps they just used some standard tool I don't know about. Pity they don't, but thanks anyway.